# Supabase Realtime makes page unresponsive on Nuxt 3 app hosted on Vercel

Tags: typescript, vue.js, real-time, supabase, nuxt3

For some reason, the realtime feature for Supabase does not work on vercel in Prod. I am able to build and run the code with no problems locally on dev and prod builds, but when I deploy to Vercel, the page becomes unresponsive.

Help Please!!!

```
<template>
  <div class="px-2">
    <TimelineTextArea :postSent="postSent" class="hidden md:inline p-2 md:p-12"/>
    <div class="w-full">
        <div v-for="post in store.posts.reverse()" :key="post.id">
            <TimelinePost :post="post"/>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
    import type { RealtimeChannel } from '@supabase/supabase-js'
    definePageMeta({
        layout: 'dashboard'
    })

    const store = useTimelineStore();
    const supabase = useSupabaseClient();
    const userPostInQueue = ref(false);
    const newPosts:Ref<Post[]> = ref([])

    function postSent(value: String) {
        store.addNewPost(value)
        userPostInQueue.value = true
    }

    onBeforeMount(() => {
        const dashboard = useDashboardStore()
        dashboard.setSelectedOption("home");
        store.loadData()
    })

    watchEffect( () => {

        const realtimeChannel = supabase
            .channel('timeline_post')
            .on('postgres_changes', { event: 'INSERT', schema: 'public', table: 'timeline' }, payload => {
                newPosts.value.push(payload.new as Post);
                if (userPostInQueue.value) {
                    store.recievedNewPost(newPosts.value as Post[])
                    userPostInQueue.value = false;
                }
                console.log("new post!");
        });

        realtimeChannel.subscribe();

        onBeforeUnmount(() => {
            realtimeChannel.unsubscribe();
        })
    })



    async function observeTimeline() {
        await store.loadData();

        return;
    }
</script>
```

I have been able to isolate the location of the problem to here:

```
        const realtimeChannel = supabase
            .channel('timeline_post')
            .on('postgres_changes', { event: 'INSERT', schema: 'public', table: 'timeline' }, payload => {
                newPosts.value.push(payload.new as Post);
                if (userPostInQueue.value) {
                    store.recievedNewPost(newPosts.value as Post[])
                    userPostInQueue.value = false;
                }
                console.log("new post!");
        });
```

Comment: Have you tried a different hosting provider to see if this might be a provider related isssue?